# sufficient condition for equivalent norms

Tags: functional-analysis

I am writing this question with respect to the following answered question [Two (equivalent ?) norms on Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591526/two-equivalent-norms-on-hilbert-space) that I feel a little uncertain of.
Then, I know that under the standard euclidean norm, $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)dx$, which induces the standard euclidean metric, $\|f\| = \langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}$, the space $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle) = \{ f | \|f\|_2<\infty\}$ is a Hilbert space.

Further define a strictly positive weight function $w:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}w(x)dx = 1$, $w(x)> 0$ for all $w\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\|w\|_\infty <\infty$. Then I can define the weighted inner product by $\langle f,g\rangle_w = \int f(x)g(x)w(x)dx$, with induced norm $\|f\|_w = \langle f,f,\rangle_w^{1/2}$. Then, $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2) = \{f | \|f\|_w<\infty\}$, the space of all functions that are square integrable with respect to the weight $w$, is also a Hilbert space.

We also have the following inequality:

$$
\|f\|_w^2 = \int f(x)^2w(x)dx \leq \|w\|_\infty\int f(x)^2dx = \|w\|_\infty \|f\|_2
$$

which implies that $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2) \subset L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w)$.

**Question:** Are these two norms equivalent?

Based off the question on stackexchange that I have referenced above, this is the following line of thought that I am going with.

Define a linear operator $T: L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w) \mapsto L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ by the following mapping $T(f)= f$. Given the definition of T we have that $T$ is injective. 
Furthermore, by our inequality, since $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2) \subset L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w)$ we must also have that $T$ is surjective.

Under this construction, I believe that $T$ is a bijection and by the open mapping theorem, if $T$ is bounded, then $T^{-1}$ is also bounded. All that remains is to show that $T$ is bounded. By the closed graph theorem, we just need to show that if for any sequence $\|f_n-f\|_w \rightarrow 0$ and $\|Tf_n-g\|_2 = \|f_n-g\|_2\rightarrow 0$ then $f=g$ implies that $T$ is bounded.

Indeed, this is true since $\|f_n-g\|_w \leq \|f_n-g\|_2 \rightarrow 0$ and so we have that

$$
\|g-f\|_w \leq \|g-f_n\|_w + \|f_n-f\|_w \rightarrow 0\,,
$$

and since $w(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we must have that $g=f$ almost everywhere. Hence $T$ is bounded.

Since both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are bounded, it is an immediate consequence that both $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_w$ are equivalent.

**I feel like I've done something `handwavey' somewhere but I can't seem to pinpoint it.. Is this just a dream come true of a result or am I missing something fundamental?**

**BONUS QUESTION What are sufficient conditions on the weight function $w$ necessary to ensure that $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_w$ are equivalent norms?**

Comment: I think I may have found a counterexample. Take $w(x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\lvert x \rvert}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now if we take $f(x) = e^{\lvert x\rvert /2}$, this function would be in $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_w )$ but clearly this function can't be in the usual $L_2$. I'll try to find the error in the reasoning and write out an answer, but it may take a while.

Comment: My thoughts on that are the fact that the linear operator isn't defined for such a function $f(x)$.. maybe that's where it is, I'm not sure. Or the fact that my linear operator $T$ is only well defined on the co-domain $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2)\cap L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w) = L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2)$ which is not closed under $\|\cdot\|_w$.... hrmm.....

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought, really if you want $T(f) = f$ be well defined you already have to require that $T(f) = f \in L_2(\mathbb{R}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ for all $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_w)$. So in order for $T$ to be well defined, you already have to assume $L_2(\mathbb{R}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_w)$ and $L_2(\mathbb{R}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ are the same.

Comment: well the thing is, in my mind the underlying vector space for both hilbert spaces is simply the space of all functions, which when induced by the different inner products leads to two differnt hilbert spaces. Going to the referred question on stackexchange, it almost looks like the two norms should be equivalent then, or is my interpretation of that wrong as well

Comment: maybe that's not necessarily true, because I restrict $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2)$ to the vector space of functions such that $\|f\|_2 <\infty$, and therefore the underlying vector space for both $L_2(\mathbb{R},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ and $L_2(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w)$ are different.

Comment: Yes that is my exact point. Really what you're assuming in your argument is that $\| f\|_w < +\infty$ implies that $\|f\|_2 < +\infty$, which is a pretty strong assumption.

Comment: Ok I agree with that. I wonder what are some sufficient conditions on $w$ to ensure that they are equivalent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your operator $T : L^2_w \to L^2$ is not well-defined, since there are $f \in L^2_w$ which do not belong to $L^2$.

In fact, under your assumptions, the norms are *never* equivalent. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. From $\int w = 1$ and $w > 0$, we find a measurable set $A \subset \mathbb R$ with positive Lebesgue measure and $w \le \varepsilon$ a.e. on $A$. Now, we define the function
$$f_\varepsilon = \chi_A,$$
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$ (it is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ outside of $A$).
Now, an easy calculation shows
$$\|f_\varepsilon\|_2 = \sqrt{\mu(A)},
\qquad \| f _\varepsilon \|_w \le \varepsilon \, \sqrt{\mu(A)},$$
where $\mu(A)> 0$ is the measure of $A$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, your norms cannot be equivalent.

Comment: that's a nice counterexample